# why doesn't message.channel.send() work here?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

i'm making a discord bot for a server using discord.py, and i'm struggling with making it send messages; i've tried using `pybot.send(msgvar)`, but it didn't work,
i've read the documentation on discord.py, also didn't help; then i found this code online:

```
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
      return
  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
      await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

and it worked!
but then when i tried to implement it in another function:

```
async def on_ready():
  msgvar = "Liberty Prime is online. All systems nominal. Weapons hot. Mission: the destruction of any and all Chinese communists."
  print(msgvar)
  await channel.send(msgvar)
  msgvar = "Voice module online. Audio functionality test initialized. Designation: Liberty Prime. Mission: the liberation of Anchorage, Alaska."
  print(msgvar)
  await channel.send(msgvar)
```

and it didn't work in that function.
why is that?
//edit, added a suggestion to my code,

```
async def on_ready():
  channel = discord.Client.get_channel(797012728149442600)
  msgvar = "Liberty Prime is online. All systems nominal. Weapons hot. Mission: the destruction of any and all Chinese communists."
  print(msgvar)
  await channel.send(msgvar)
  msgvar = "Voice module online. Audio functionality test initialized. Designation: Liberty Prime. Mission: the liberation of Anchorage, Alaska."
  print(msgvar)
  await channel.send(msgvar)
```

and it gave me a diffrent error: "TypeError: get_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'"

Comment: Adding the error message is highly suggested when asking questions like this. Although in this case it's quite obvious. The `on_message` function has the argument `message` and `await message.channel.send(msgvar)` uses that argument. When you use it in `on_ready` message is not defined. I don't know enough about discord bots to tell you exactly how to fix your problem but I am sure there is a way to get the channel object of the channel you want to send to.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `discord.Channel` instance in order to send message to a specific channel. In `on_message` event, you can get it by using it's `message` parameter but in `on_ready` event, there's no `message` parameter or variable, so you can't get channel instance by using `message.channel` in `on_ready`. There are other ways to get a channel instance like [`discord.Client.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel).

```py
async def on_ready():
  channel = client.get_channel(<channel id>)
  msgvar = "Liberty Prime is online. All systems nominal. Weapons hot. Mission: the destruction of any and all Chinese communists."
  print(msgvar)
  await channel.send(msgvar)
  msgvar = "Voice module online. Audio functionality test initialized. Designation: Liberty Prime. Mission: the liberation of Anchorage, Alaska."
  print(msgvar)
  await channel.send(msgvar)
```

Comment: well it gave me a diffrent error "TypeError: get_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'" even though i entered the channel id in the function

Comment: Can you update your post with your recent code?

Comment: You need an instance of `discord.Client` or `discord.ext.commands.Bot`. What is the line before `async def on_ready`?